# parameter different significantly if I split the data alternatively

Tags: regression, predictive-models, multilevel-analysis

Let's say I have linear regression model, and assume $\beta$ is the parameter.
Assume the design matrix $X = (x_0,x_1,x_2,...x_n)$

If I split the data alternatively, like this:

$$
X^{(0)} = (x_0,x_2,x_4,...x_{2k})
$$

$$
X^{(1)} = (x_1,x_3,x_5,...x_{2k+1})
$$

and then fit the model using $X^{(0)}$, $X^{(1)}$ by solving least square. I would get two different parameter $\beta^{(0)}$, $\beta^{(1)}$.

What I find is that $\beta^{(0)}$ has a significant different from $\beta^{(1)}$:

[image]

This plot is created by a sliding-window and then fit each window to get $\beta^{(0)}$, $\beta^{(1)}$. i.e.

For $t=0$, fit $(x_0,x_2,x_4,...x_{2k})$ for $\beta^{(0)}_t$

For $t=1$, fit $(x_2,x_4,x_6,...x_{2k+2})$ for $\beta^{(0)}_t$

For $t=2$, fit $(x_4,x_6,x_8,...x_{2k+4})$ for $\beta^{(0)}_t$

...

For $t=0$, fit $(x_1,x_3,x_5,...x_{2k+1})$ for $\beta^{(1)}_t$

For $t=1$, fit $(x_3,x_5,x_7,...x_{2k+3})$ for $\beta^{(1)}_t$

For $t=2$, fit $(x_5,x_7,x_9,...x_{2k+5})$ for $\beta^{(1)}_t$

...

and then plot $t$ vs $\beta^{(0)}_t$ and $t$ vs $\beta^{(1)}_t$ . Intended to discover if the parameter is the same across the time.

The model is not of one degree-of-freedom, I just plot one problematic parameter to show the situation.

The data is a real life data. I would use the model for prediction purpose.

My questions are:

(1) What I should do to model such different? It is a clearly violation for the model assumption that each observation is independent.

(2) How I split the data into $(x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is based on different group of the data and indeed the index $0,1,2,...,n$ is ordered by time. Is a mixed-effect model with a AR(1) like covariance structure relevant here? OR I should try dynamic linear model?

(3) I cannot find a meaningful reason to explain why splitting $X^{(0)}$, $X^{(1)}$ is relevant here. That's mean I cannot find an indicator variable to split data into 2 groups and fit a random slope model. Of course I can intentionally split the data alternatively like what I am doing now. However, I need to use the model for prediction, how can I know whether the next observation is in which group if I do not know the reason?

Comment: I have no idea what the plot is, sorry. What are you sliding? What is x in that plot? In a linear regression each B is estimated once.

Comment: I edited. I plot it because I want to know if the parameter is the same. OR I should use other method?

Comment: What is t? What is x? This still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: $t$ is the time. The index in the subscript. $x_t$ is the data point indexed by $t$

Comment: OK, then you have a time series, which wasn't clear at all from the question. Time series have their own problems.

Comment: Yes. You can call it a time series. But I am not modelling it as a time series. The reason why I plot this graph is to CHECK if the parameter $\beta$ change over time. If not, I can model it reasonably with OLS. What I discover is that the parameter is nearly constant but if I split the data alternatively, the parameter is different and give rise to my questions. How should I model such oscillation? Provided that I have no a priori reason to split the data in this way.